# How connect to MSK cluster from EKS cluster

Tags: amazon-eks, aws-msk

I am having difficulties connecting to my MSK cluster from my EKS cluster even though both clusters share **the same VPC and the same subnets**.

The security group used by the MSK cluster has the following inbound rules

| type | protocol | port range | source |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| all traffic | all | all | custom | SG_ID |
| all traffic | all | all | anywhere ipv4 | 0.0.0.0/0 |

Where SG_ID is the EKS' *Cluster security group*.
The one labeled: EKS created security group applied...

In the EKS cluster, I am using the following commands to test connectivity:

```
kubectl  run kafka-consumer \
-ti \
--image=quay.io/strimzi/kafka:latest-kafka-2.8.1 \
--rm=true \
--restart=Never \
-- bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --topic test  --bootstrap-server b-1.test.z35y0w.c4.kafka.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:9092 --replication-factor 2 --partitions 1 --if-not-exists
```

With the following result

> Error while executing topic command : Call(callName=createTopics, deadlineMs=1635906680860, tries=1, nextAllowedTryMs=1635906680961) timed out at 1635906680861 after 1 attempt(s)
> [2021-11-03 02:31:20,865] ERROR org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=createTopics, deadlineMs=1635906680860, tries=1, nextAllowedTryMs=1635906680961) timed out at 1635906680861 after 1 attempt(s)
> Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: createTopics
> (kafka.admin.TopicCommand$)
> pod "kafka-consumer" deleted
> pod default/kafka-consumer terminated (Error)

Sadly, the second bootstrap server displayed on the MSK Page gives the same result.

nc eventually times out

```
kubectl  run busybox -ti --image=busybox --rm=true --restart=Never -- nc b-2.test.z35y0w.c4.kafka.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

nslookup fails as well

```
kubectl  run busybox -ti --image=busybox --rm=true --restart=Never -- nslookup b-2.test.z35y0w.c4.kafka.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.
*** Can't find b-2.test.z35y0w.c4.kafka.us-east-1.amazonaws.com: No answer
```

Could anyone please give me a hint?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I need to connect MSK from my EKS pod. So I searched this doc, I want to share my solution, hope can help others:
This my config file:

```
root@kain:~/work# cat kafkaconfig
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.mechanism=AWS_MSK_IAM
sasl.jaas.config=software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule required;
```

sasl.client.callback.handler.class=software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler

This is my command:

```
./kafka-topics.sh --list --bootstrap-server <My MSK bootstrap server>:9098 --command-config ./kafkaconfig
```

For this command, there are 2 preconditions we need to make sure,

1. one is you have access to aws msk, (I access MSK from my eks pod, and my eks pod has OIDC to access the AWS).
2. Second is we need to has AWS auth jar file: aws-msk-iam-auth.jar
   address: https://github.com/aws/aws-msk-iam-auth/releases
   put it to kafkaclient libs directory or export CLASSPATH=/aws-msk-iam-auth-1.1.4-all.jar

reference doc: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/securing-apache-kafka-is-easy-and-familiar-with-iam-access-control-for-amazon-msk/